# Multithread with several email account sending to a list of recipients?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, mail-sender

My goal is speed up process of send emails, because send only with 1 email account will delay a long time when have a big list of recipients.

Then i have a txt file with several email account each line is equal to this:

- **smtp.company.fr**|**marketing@company.fr**|**emailpass**|**587**

Then i want create a quantity of threads equals to number of lines of this txt file ( with clarity if is greater than it, will cause errors :-) ) passing each info between "|" delimiter as parameter to each thread.

All emails recipients will be present in a unique `Memo` (line by line) and my app not must send same message to the same recipient once already sent.

I have a example about how create several threads, but i not know how pass these parameters to each thread created:

```
type 
   TMyThread = class(TThread) 
   private 
   protected 
      procedure Execute; override; 
   public 
      constructor Create; 
   end; 

constructor TMyThread.Create; 
begin 
   inherited True; 
   FreeOnTerminate := True; 
   Priority := tpNormal; 
end; 

//=================================================================

var 
   I: Integer; 
   MyThreadList: array [0..2] of TMyThread; // creates two threads
begin 
   for I := 0 to High(MyThreadList) do 
   begin 
      MyThreadList[I] := TMyThread.Create(True); 
      MyThreadList[I].FreeOnTerminate := True; 
      MyThreadList[I].Priority := tpNormal; 
      MyThreadList[I].Resume; 
   end; 
end;
```

*Also if exist some better idea to speed up process of send emails using only 1 email account, will be welcome.*

Comment: I would recommend as much threads as the machine can handle at once (using system thread pool can help in this). Having more won't bring any performance increase.

Comment: Be prepared to get your mail server blacklisted. That's a sure way to do so. You should seriously consider using an email service such as MailChimp / Mandrill to prevent such issues.

Comment: @Victoria, thank you by your suggestion, but i'm searching performance. In others words, send a max quantity of emails possible with good speed (ex: 10 email sent/second).

Comment: Threads aren't magical performance solutions. You have other bottlenecks, such as your CPU, Network / Internet speed, disk speed (if you're loading files to email), etc. Sending 10 emails at the same time doesn't make much difference whether it's in one thread or 10 threads. And again, sending any amount of bulk email is begging to get blacklisted, especially at the rate of 10/second. If you don't wish to use another service, then I'd suggest if anything make them *slower*, not *faster*.

Comment: Why would number of cpus be relevant. This is not a cpu bound task.

Comment: @MarcioGomes: "*ex: 10 email sent/second*" - you do realize that you can send a single email to more than 1 recipient at a time, don't you?  Extra recipients won't take more time, since you are only sending 1 copy of the email to the SMTP server, and then it will copy the email to each recipient for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes, for example, brute force programs seems not worry with this.

Comment: @David It depends - for example, perhaps OP needs to build each email body, in which case the CPU may be used a bit more.

Comment: @Jerry, single CPU can process more than one thread context at a time.

Comment: @jerry I did not say, "uses the cpu", I said "cpu bound".

Comment: @Victoria Yes I know this, that wasn't my point though. Actually that kinda supports my point.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you want say with BCC?

Comment: @David And I said "the CPU may be used a bit more." "Bottleneck" as in the speed of the CPU, for example.

Comment: @jerry You aren't making sense to me. I wonder if you know what the term "cpu bound" means.

Comment: @MarcioGomes: That is one way to do it. But you can also have multiple recipients in `TO` and `CC`, too.  An SMTP client combines the individual entries of `TO`, `CC` and `BCC` into a single list and then sends that list to the SMTP server, followed by the actual email. The server then delivers (or forwards) the email to each recipient it was told.

Comment: @David Of course I know what "cpu bound" means - as I said, suppose OP needs to build each email body just before sending. Suppose it requires an intensive loop, or many loops, just to prepare a single email. We don't know this obviously, but my point is that there are other bottlenecks which affect speed, and simply spawning a bunch of threads is not a magical solution. I learned that from you, actually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, i already knew, but i want send emails without my clients (users) see that was sent to more someone. Then this way we back to my initial idea :-)

Comment: @MarcioGomes: what you described is exactly what BCC is designed for. But that has nothing to do with HOW you send the emails using 1+ SMTP servers at a time.

Comment: @JerryDodge, yes about this: `Suppose it requires an intensive loop, or many loops, just to prepare a single email.` you guessed. I not see other way to do this, because `IdMessage` in each loop, for example must be setting address of a different recipient each time also random strings in Subject before send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass parameters to a thread, simply add input parameters to `TMyThread`'s constructor.  Either as individual `string` values (`Host`, `Port`, `Username`, `Password`, etc), or as a `TStringList`, or a `record`, whatever you are comfortable passing.  The constructor can then save the data in members of the class for `Execute()` to use as needed.  In this regard, threads don't work any differently than any other class.  Only that `Execute()` runs in a different context than the constructor does.

I suggest you use a thread pool with a couple of thread-safe lists.  One list of SMTP providers, and one list of recipients.  Create a thread pool with only as many threads as there are installed CPUs (if more than the number of recipients being sent to).

Each thread can then do the following:

1. extract a recipient from the recipients list.  Or a handful, since a single email can be sent to multiple recipients at a time, especially if multiple recipients are on the same email domain.  If no recipient(s) are available, exit.
2. then, extract an idle SMTP provider from the providers list.  If not already connected to it, connect and login as needed.
3. then, send an email to the recipient(s).
4. then, put the SMTP provider back in the providers list (or, leave it in the list the whole time and just mark it as idle). Leave the connection open, so another thread (or even the same thread) can use the same connection on its next iteration.
5. Go back to #1.

Once all threads have finished, cleanup as needed.

Now, with that said, note that SMTP providers thwart spammers in many ways, including:

- whitelisting only known good senders, like other legitimate SMTP providers.  You can send emails using your own email provider's SMTP server, but you can't always send emails to a recipient's SMTP server directly (if they are on a different email provider than you).
- limiting how many simultaneous TCP connections you can open to them
- limiting how many emails you can send at a time
- limiting how many emails you can send within a given time period
- limiting how often you can send emails.

No amount of threading will get you past these kind of limitations.  If anything, you usually have to pay extra to remove them.

The best way to handle this kind of situation is to setup an online mailing list (such as with Yahoo Groups), and then you can send 1 email to 1 address and let the mailing list provider distribute the email to subscribed members for you.